# JasperReports: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I try to use a report on my JasperServer, which I created with the help of iReport. In iReport my report works fine and there are no errors. But when I tried to deploy the report it gives me following error in short:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date`

and the complete Error:

```
The server has encountered an error. Please excuse the inconvenience.

Error Message
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date 

Error Trace    
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setDate(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:649)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:577)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.setStatementParameter(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:399)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter$1.visit(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:332)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter$QueryParameter.accept(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:157)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRAbstractQueryExecuter.visitQueryParameters(JRAbstractQueryExecuter.java:646)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createStatement(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:317)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRJdbcQueryExecuter.java:196)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.createDatasource(JRTimezoneJdbcQueryExecuter.java:168)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.createQueryDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:1087)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.initDatasource(JRFillDataset.java:668)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1258)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:877)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:875)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$AsynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:831)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1658)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1022)
at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:897)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I uploaded the report, got the right data source (I tested it with another report already) and imported my Resources (Subreports) and input controls. I don't know whether I missed a step or so, but I am pretty sure that I did everything required. Importing every Subreport, setting input controls declare the right path `repo:mySubreports.jrxml`. If you need more information please tell me ! I think I added all information required and I don't want to spam SO with useless information because I don't know which information could be useful by now as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this has something to do with date parameters/variables in your report.

Please ensure the input control you made for the date parameters in Jasperserver are java.util.date

Also one common error i have seen myself repeating is putting a default value expresion like an empty string may be (`""`) for the date parameters/variables where they are declared .In this case i have seen the report works in ireport also gets upload in the server without any error but it would throw

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date Error Trace
```

Please check the above two points with all the date parameters of your report and update here if that works

Thanks

chandra

Comment: The second one was my problem :) Thank you very much